# Python - connection to AWS Redis Time out

Tags: python, redis

Currently I have this python code to test AWS redis conection, it fails with conection timeout. Can you help me to resolve it?

```
import redis, time, datetime, sys

endpoint='myred-0041.dpchko.0001.amazonaws.com'

def prepareConn(endpoint):
    r = redis.StrictRedis(host=endpoint, port=6379, db=0, socket_timeout=1)
    return r

r = prepareConn(endpoint)

while True:
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    try:
        print(r.set('foo','bar'))
    except:
        print "Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0]
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Did you make sure port 6379 is opened for access in security rules?

Comment: Could you try increasing the `socket_timeout` to `10`?

Comment: @BorkoKovacev i increased the timeout to be 10 still the same error 
`Unexpected error: <class 'redis.exceptions.TimeoutError'> `

Comment: @TarunLalwani u mean the port in my local ? i am using macos , the AWS redis i tested with another application developed by laravel and it worked no issue , so might be i miss somthing in code ?,

Comment: Where did you run this `php` application? Because if you ran the same in your AWS VPC then the server may have have access to redis because of VPC but no external access is enabled.

Comment: Thanks  Tarun Lalwani , your commenct  helpt me

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution , AWS has some restriction that make my local pc cann't connect to AWS Redis , then  i installed redis locally https://redis.io/ and replaced the endpoint to be endpoint='http://localhost'

but at production deploymet i use AWS redis, and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

The technique is try then keep state in an environment variable

```
class mycache():
    __redisClient = None

    def __init__(self, log=True):

        ep = ""
        try:
            ep = os.environ["REDIS_HOST"]
        except KeyError:
            pass

        if ep != "":
            self.__redisClient = redis.Redis(host=ep)
            self.__redisClient.ping()
        else:
            try:
                self.__redisClient = redis.Redis()
                self.__redisClient.ping()
            except Exception:
                ep = ebutils.get_redis_endpoint()
                self.__redisClient = redis.Redis(host=ep)
                self.__redisClient.ping()
        os.environ["REDIS_HOST"] = self.__redisClient.connection_pool.connection_kwargs["host"]
```

FYI I get end point using boto3

```
def session():
    if "REGION_NAME" in os.environ.keys():
        pass
    else:
        fname = "/tmp/aws-secrets.json"
        if not os.path.exists(fname):
            fname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), "aws-secrets.json")
        with open(fname, "r") as f:
            envjson = json.load(f)
        for k, v in envjson.items():
            os.environ[k] = v
    sess = boto3.session.Session(region_name=os.environ["REGION_NAME"],
                                 aws_access_key_id=os.environ["ACCESS_ID"],
                                 aws_secret_access_key=os.environ["ACCESS_KEY"])
    return sess

def get_redis_endpoint(cluster_id="redis-sensorvenv"):
    ec = session().client("elasticache")

    resp = ec.describe_cache_clusters(CacheClusterId = cluster_id, ShowCacheNodeInfo=True)
    return resp["CacheClusters"][0]["CacheNodes"][0]["Endpoint"]["Address"]
```